# How to align columns in list view EasyAdminBundle

Tags: symfony2-easyadmin

[image]

How can I align the numbers in columns 2,3,4 to the right ?
I tried css style with text-align but it doesn't do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Use css class for the property of list in yml like this.

```
- { property: 'col2', css_class: 'pull-right'  }
```

Best way to apply right alignment only in td use custom css like this.

```
- { property: 'col2', css_class: 'text-align-right'  }
```

In your template or layout add css:

```
{% block head_stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}
<style>
    table td.text-align-right {
        float:right !important
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it breaks the list view and make it look bad

Comment: Yes I checked it because it is also applying css to th. If you want to apply css only in td then use custom clas. Let me modify my answer.

Comment: I believe easyadmin is using Bootstrap, you should be able to use the default `text-right` class